# Unrelated Column reference with filter syntax error

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

Im using SSAS Tabular. Trying to insert a column which gets data(OrgNumber) from an unrelated table called DimCustomer.

DAX-Syntax:

```
=Calculate(Values('DimCustomer'[OrgNum]),FILTER('DimCustomer','DimCustomer'[CustomerNr]='FactTransactions'[CustomerNr])))
```

Throws back error msg:

The syntax for 'FILTER' is incorrect.
The calculated column 'FactTransactions[CalculatedColumn1]' contains a syntax error. Provide a valid formula.

Comment: Hi @Blixter if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=LOOKUPVALUE('DimCustomer'[OrgNum], 'DimCustomer'[CustomerNr], 'FactTransactions'[CustomerNr])
```

This assumes it is a calculated column on FactTransactions

Answer (score 0):

I laid out your code like the below and it seems you have an extra bracket:

```
=Calculate
(
    Values('DimCustomer'[OrgNum]),
    FILTER
    (
        'DimCustomer',
        'DimCustomer'[CustomerNr]='FactTransactions'[CustomerNr]
    )
)
)
```